# SSH with nologin user using ssh_config

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, openssh

I'd like to connect from node A to C but would like to switch to a nologin user at the same time. In ssh config I have:

```
Host B
   Hostname bb
   User a
   ForwardX11 yes
   ForwardX11Trusted yes

Host C
   Hostname cc
   User a
   ForwardX11 yes
   ForwardX11Trusted yes
   ProxyCommand ssh a@B 'netcat %h 22'
```

`ssh -t a@C 'sudo -u serviceuser bash'` **works fine**.

However, I'd like to ssh to the node with one single "ssh user@host"
command, which can be used in file managers which doesn't support additional ssh parameters.
I tried using:

```
Host D
   User a
   RequestTTY yes
   ProxyCommand ssh a@C 'sudo -u serviceuser bash'
```

this, and its variants (/usr/bin/bash ..etc) always return

```
bash: line 1: $'SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9\r': command not found
```

What would be the correct way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. The proxy commands in `ssh_config` are for IO redirect, which is preferred way of doing multi-hop connections. You can not specify the command that should be run on the remote server in there.

The beset you could do is bash alias or function to save you typing.

Comment: Thanks, I see. Is it possible then to forward port to localhost and at the same time execute that command?

Comment: Yes. Simply using `LocalForward` option (or `-L` switch). When you will use `ProxyCommand`, it will forward all the way from remote over the middles to the local computer.